# Finite sub cover

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

In the definition of compact set: From any open cover $E=\cup_{i\in I} U_i$ we can find a finite sub-cover $E=\cup_{k=1}^NU_{i_k}$?

Is the finite sub-cover is always open please?

Thank you.

Comment: No. And it's "finite."

Comment: Thank you so your are sure that a finite sub-cover is not alwayse open

Comment: No, a subcover of an open cover is an open cover.

Comment: $U_{i_k}$ is alwayse open ?

Comment: Sure, the subcover is made up of open sets, after all they are sets chosen from the original collection of open sets in the open cover.  But you have a mistake, $E$ is not necessarily the finite union, the finite union  just covers the original compact set $K$.

Comment: That's the definition of an open cover. Choosing fewer open sets doesn't change whether the individual sets are open.

Comment: but when we say $U_{i_k}$ then there are parts from U_i and parts of open sets are not alwayse open

Comment: @Vrouvrou No, $\{U_{i_k}\}$ is a subset of $\{U_{\lambda}\}$.

Comment: who is $\{U_{\lambda}\}$ ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou there are no "parts" here.  Compactness means that if you have some infinite set of open sets that cover the space, you actually only need a finite number of them to cover it.  At no point do you need to split up or take parts of any of the open sets in your covering, you simply select a finite subset of them.

Comment: @DanSimon but if it is like this why there is in bokks this notation $U_{i_k}$ if it is like you say we must jute find U_k such that $k\in\{1,\ldots,N\}$

Comment: Yes I think the notation in whatever book you're using is a little odd, but it makes sense.  $E = \bigcup^{N}_{k=1} U_{i_k}$ simply means $E$ is the union of a finite number of the $U_i$ (indexed by k < N) in the original covering, which is the definition of a finite sub-covering.

Comment: for example in the co finite topology $\tau=\{G\subset E, card(E\setminus G)<\infty\}\cup\{\emptyset\}$, $card(E)=\infty$, if we let $E\subset \cup_{i\in I} A_i$ where $A_i$ are open then $E\setminus A_i$ is finite and we have for each i,  $E\subset (E\setminus A_i )\cup A_i$ it is a finite sub cover and not only open $A_i$ is open where $E\setminus A_i$ is closed the union is $E$ which is closed and open

Comment: the book is from 2011, * in the example i give E is not compact because it is not Hausdorff